# I can't tell if my GeoJSON file is too large for openlayers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2

I am a bit new to this GIS thing. I have shapefile that I fed to geoserver in order to retrieve a GeoJson file. I was attempting to display this on openlayers, but it won't show anything. The file is a feature collection of  2450 multipolygons, that is about 2.2 mb big. I tried reducing it to only 3 features, but it does not seem to show anything at all.

However, if I open the browser console, I can see that I did load 3 features, even though they are not painted in the map. I am not sure if they are too small be visible, or if I have to supply a special style for multipolygons.

When I try to load my whole geojson file, it still won't show anything, but in the console I can see that only 50 features were loaded. Moreover they were loaded in a very odd order. Probably because it is stored as a tree.

```
[42, 34, 24, 36, 33, 31, 22, 43, 44, 21, 28, 47, 16, 49, 32, 40, 39, 19, 38, 50, 25, 37, 27, 1, 2, 3, 9, 8, 12, 10, 11, 7, 5, 18, 20, 45, 41, 23, 35, 30, 26, 4, 17, 48, 15, 14, 29, 6, 13, 46]
```

So, how can I get it to load more than 50 features? I am using [this example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/vector-layer.html)  as a template, which loads 176 features just fine.

So, what's wrong with those 50 features that won't show up in the map?

Am I missing something? Would a PostGis connection solve this? If so, could you please point me to the right tutorial? I am feeling quite overwhelmed by this :s

**UPDATE:**

It turns out I wasn't able to see any of the 50 features that actually got loaded because I set the wrong projection in geoserver. I still don't know why I am only getting 50 features though.

**Better Update:**
It turns out that geoserver has a setting for maximum number of features set to 50. I disabled that and got the whole set of features that is about 123 mb big!

I am guessing this is a very poor way to get my data read.

Comment: Alex's points are good, but you could also look at vector tiles (mbtiles, being  more or less the standard and TopoJSON, which is a way of compressing JSON (up to 80%, it is claimed), using nodes and arcs, so each linestring is only sent once.

Answer (score 2):

If you're wanting to display a lot of data, use WMS, which is a rendered image-based system. And then if you still want to have interactivity, you can do that using vectors.

Check out this: https://github.com/alexgleith/maps-website/blob/master/stormwater.html#L151

This is a pretty complex example, and it uses leaflet rather than openlayers, but the core idea is that you use WMS for viewing and WFS for interactivity.

Comment: It is a good example. There are also TopoJSON and vector tiles as alternatives, of course.